# Update with join results in ambiguous field error

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have models:

```
User(id)   # has_many tasks through projects
Project(id, user_id, done:boolean)
Task(project_id, done:boolean)
```

I'm trying to update a user's tasks `done` field, but I get an ambiguous field error because both the Project and Task have a `done` field.

The SQL generated for marking all tasks of a user as done, is something like:

```
>> @user.tasks.update_all(done: true)

UPDATE tasks
INNER JOIN projects ON projects.id = tasks.project_id
SET done = 1
WHERE projects.user_id = 2548
```

I tried doing this:

```
@user.tasks.update_all("tasks.done" => true)
```

But that returns unknown field `tasks.done` which is weird as i used to specify table names on select queries and it worked.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `@user.tasks.update_all("tasks.done = 1")`

Answer (score 1):

This will be shortest suggestion :)

```
@user.tasks.update_all(done: true)
```